# Why loop exits before exit conditon is satisfied?

Tags: c, function, loops

I need help figuring out why the loop breaks before it gets 5 values as it is supposed. I'm burning my head and can't find the bug.
All help is appreciated.
The code is supposed to accept 5 values of colors, check if they are allowed and compare the inserted code with the one randomly generated. If they exist and are equal in the same index in array marks black++ if it is right but in wrong place marks white++.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h> 
#define QTD  5   // Number of colors
#define MAX 10   // Number of characters in string
#define DIM  5   // Number of colors in vector colors

// Function to compare inserted color with array of random colors
int identical(int i, char secretCodigoCores[5][10],
        char tentativaCode[5][10]) {

    for (int j = 0 ; j < QTD ; j++) 
    {
        if(tentativaCode[i] == secretCodigoCores[i])
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0; 
}

//function to check if inserted colors have common colors with array of random  
void commom(char secretCodigoCores[5][10],char tentativaCode[5][10],
        int white,int black,int i) {
   
    for(i = 0; i < QTD ;i++) 
    {
        if(tentativaCode[i] == secretCodigoCores[i])
        {   
            black++;
            continue;
        }

       if(identical(i,secretCodigoCores,tentativaCode)==1)
       {
           white++; 
       }      
    }    
    printf("\n%d Right colors in wrong place",white);
    printf("\n%d Right colors in right place",black);
}

int main(){

    srand(time(NULL));
    int i=0,j=0, option=1, black=0, white=0, wrongTentativa;
    char secretCodigoCores[4][10], tentativaCode[4][10];
    char colors[5][10] = {"green", "red", "blue", "yellow", 
    "brown"}; //Allowed colors
    char input[10];

    char *mensagem;
    mensagem="Welcome to the game";
    int tentativas=0,max_tentativas=5,tentativas_restantes=0;
    tentativas_restantes=max_tentativas - tentativas;

    clear();
    printf("%s:\n", mensagem);
    secretRandomCores(secretCodigoCores);

    exibeTabuleiro();
    for (tentativas = 0; tentativas < max_tentativas; tentativas++)
    {
        tentativa(tentativaCode,input,colors);
        commom(tentativaCode,secretCodigoCores,white,black,i);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In main `char *input[MAX];jogo(input[MAX]);` is access out of bounds.

Comment: `input` has no memory allocation. It's just an array of uninitialised pointers.

Comment: A lot of compiler warnings: https://godbolt.org/z/rvPfKoE7j

Comment: `cores` appears a lot of times with different definitions. In `crearCodigoCores(cores);` it decays into a pointer to the first element, a `char * (*)[10]` but the function takes a `char (*)[10]`. Not the same thing

Comment: If you are using GCC I suggest to compile with options `-Wall -Wextra` to enable compiler warnings and `-g -fsanitize=address,undefined` to enable memory access checks at run-time.

Comment: `-Werror -pedantic-errors` will probably help too.

Comment: Too much code. Please fix a [mre]

Comment: Not only is `jogo(input[MAX])` an out of bounds reference, it is the wrong type. `jogo` is supposed to take a `char *`, but `input[i]` is a `char`.

Comment: `strcpy` has no side effects, so what is the point of the `switch(randColor)`?  The entire statement is a no-op and will be optimized away.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. I did get to learn a lot more by checking all your inputs. I manage to rectify the code and as suggested by klutt I reduced the code.

Comment: but...now this part doesnt do what is supposed to do

Comment: I change the code for the part not working, although I manage to solve the problem with if(strcmp(tentativaCode[i],secretCodigoCores[i])==0)